# HTML5 Layout with Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to code a layout like this with Bootstrap 3.x

[image]

But I don't know how to create a section (in this case, the main and the article) with multiple columns size, without a markup error related to close the elements.

The following code is correct syntactically, but it doesn't respect the layout (the col-md-4 is in a new row)

```html
  <body>
  <header>
   <!-- menu -->
  </header>

   <div class="container">
   <main>
  <article>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
       <p>Lorem ipsum</p>

     <p>Lorem ipsum</p>

     <p>Lorem ipsum</p>

     <p>Etc., etc.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </article>
   </main>
    <div class="row">
   <aside class="col-md-4">
       <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
   </aside>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <footer class="col-md-12">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
     </footer>

 </div><!-- container -->
   
  </body>
</html>
```

What do you suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Green" column, **.col-md-4** should be a sibling of "orange" column **.col-md-8**. They need to have the same **.row** parent. In other words, they should be next to each other, that way the sections won't break. Here is how I would do it:

```
<header>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">header</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>

<main>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">orange section</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">orange section</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">green section</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</main>

<footer>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">footer</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Yes, but we need an aside (green column) outside the main and article elements (orange column)